# Run specific JMH benchmarks from jar

Tags: java, jmh

I have a several heavy benchmark classes annotated with @Benchmark. After bulding jar with benchmarks I can run all of them with following command

```
java -Xmx4G -jar benchmarks.jar -f 1 -wi 3 -i 10
```

How to specify benchmarks to run, if I don't want to run all of them?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When in doubt, ask for command line help. In fact, running the JAR with `-h` yields:

```
Usage: java -jar ... [regexp*] [options]
 [opt] means optional argument.
 <opt> means required argument.
 "+" means comma-separated list of values.
 "time" arguments accept time suffixes, like "100ms".

  [arguments]                 Benchmarks to run (regexp+).
```

So, supplying a regular expression as the filter helps.

Answer (score 7):

This is the exact command:

```
java -Xmx4G -jar benchmarks.jar YourClass -f 1 -wi 3 -i 10
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please include a brief explanation of how/why the above helps solve the problem. From [Review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/15432679).

Comment: @Leigh There is no problem. Just a simple question to which I give a simple answer.

Comment: Simple to you perhaps :) Not everyone reading this will have the same skill level. So adding a brief explanation makes it more helpful, to a broader range of users.

Comment: @Leight The other answer already has an explanation which I don't want to repeat. My answer adds a precise command to run which is missing in that answer.

Comment: It is up to you. Anyway, I get what you mean and do not want keep "beating a dead horse" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Aleksey's answer, use a regular expression filter on the test class name.

```
java -jar myJmh.jar -f 1 -wi 1 -w 10 -i 5 "JwtParseBenchmark"
java -jar myJmh.jar -f 1 -wi 1 -w 10 -i 5 "JwtClaimBenchmark"
```

and/or run multiple using for example

```
java -jar myJmh.jar -f 1 -wi 1 -w 10 -i 5 "Jwt.*Benchmark"
```