# Flink Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: maven, apache-flink, jmh

I'm trying to run those Flink Benchmarks:
https://github.com/dataArtisans/flink-benchmarks

I've generated the jar file using maven with that command:

```
mvn clean package -Pbuild-jar
```

Then I'm trying to run the benchmark on a Flink Cluster with that command:

```
./bin/flink run -c org.apache.flink.benchmark.WindowBenchmarks ~/flinkBenchmarks/target/flink-hackathon-benchmarks-0.1.jar
```

I've used the -c option to add to the classpath the Main of the benchmark (WindowBenchmarks) I want to run.

Finally, I get that error:

```html
# JMH version: 1.19
# VM version: JDK 1.8.0_151, VM 25.151-b12
# VM invoker: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java
# VM options: -Dlog.file=/home/user/flink-1.3.2/flink-dist/target/flink-1.3.2-bin/flink-1.3.2/log/flink-user-client-mypc.log -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/home/user/flink-1.3.2/flink-dist/target/flink-1.3.2-bin/flink-1.3.2/conf/log4j-cli.properties -Dlogback.configurationFile=file:/home/user/flink-1.3.2/flink-dist/target/flink-1.3.2-bin/flink-1.3.2/conf/logback.xml -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
# Warmup: 10 iterations, 1 s each
# Measurement: 10 iterations, 1 s each
# Timeout: 10 min per iteration
# Threads: 1 thread, will synchronize iterations
# Benchmark mode: Throughput, ops/time
# Benchmark: org.apache.flink.benchmark.WindowBenchmarks.sessionWindow

# Run progress: 0.00% complete, ETA 00:04:00
# Fork: 1 of 3
Error: Could not find or load main class org.openjdk.jmh.runner.ForkedMain
<forked VM failed with exit code 1>
<stdout last='20 lines'>
</stdout>
<stderr last='20 lines'>
Error: Could not find or load main class org.openjdk.jmh.runner.ForkedMain
</stderr>

# Run complete. Total time: 00:00:00

Benchmark  Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units

The program didn't contain a Flink job. Perhaps you forgot to call execute() on the execution environment.
```

I don't have any previous experience with Flink and Maven so I find out what is missing. My first thought was that it's a missing dependencies error, but they look fine. Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you check whether "org.openjdk.jmh.runner.ForkedMain" is contained in the jar?

Comment: Alright i could reproduce it locally even though the class is in the jar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`flink-benchmarks` is a repository that contains sets of micro benchmarks designed to run on single machine, not on the cluster. The `main` functions defined in the various classes (test cases) are 'JMH' runners, not Flink programs. As such you can either execute whole benchmark suite (which takes ~1hour):

`mvn -Dflink.version=1.5.0 clean install exec:exec`

or if you want to execute just one benchmark, the best approach is to execute selected main function manually. For example from your IDE (don't forget about selecting `flink.version`, default value for the property is defined in `pom.xml`).

There is also [a possibility to execute single benchmark from console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660599/run-specific-jmh-benchmarks-from-jar), but I haven't tried it for very long time.

Comment: Thank you Piotr. The benchmark creators say that can be run on a Flink cluster. The provided instructions in the pom file say that, in order to run the benchmark on a cluster you need to generate the jar file using `mvn clean package -Pbuild-jar` as a first step. Then you input the jar file in the flink cluster. My problem is on that step because it seems that something is missing but I cant find it out.

Comment: You're welcome. However I can assure you that it wasn't intended use case, since it happens that I'm the original creator of those benchmarks alongside Nico :) This pom was probably copied over or created by a script and that's why it ended up with so misleading pom. Sorry about that (this project was created as a part of hackathon) - I have already fixed that and added proper readme.

Comment: Thanks for adding the readme, it is clear and helpful. That I'd like to ask is at what point of the pom file, flink is actually initialized and how you set it up. I can't find the piece of code doing so. The only way I can see that Flink could be initialized is in the jmh.Main class, since I cant find it anywhere else in the pom file or in the internal Maven building and packaging. Have you altered the jmh.Main code to set up flink? Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry for responding so late @OrionPapadakis, I have only now noticed your question.

Some of the benchmarks in `flink-benchmarks` are not using Flink at all, but setting up some module/class tests. Others are running Flink applications using `LocalExecutionEnvironment`, which is exactly the same which you would use to run Flink application on your local machine, without submitting the job to a cluster.

Comment: Hi @PiotrNowojski we recently created some jmh metrics too (testing the states behavior with our objects or even some process functions) and I was wondering how you 'read' your results? Do you compare with something? How you know if you made a mistake and decrease the performance? I was thinking to implement a enum with baseline results, hardcode them (based on your or jenkins machine) and just compare with the current results but this doesn't seems right to me. Do you have another idea orsomething other already implemented in flink?

Comment: In Flink we have built a bit of an infrastructure around [Codespeed UI](https://github.com/tobami/codespeed). We execute benchmarks on a bare metal machine (a jenkins worker), and we upload the results to the Codespeed  using a simple [script](https://github.com/apache/flink-benchmarks/blob/master/save_jmh_result.py). Codespeed provides you some graphs, with very rudimentary trends comparison.